# Flask session quites as soon as selenium script finishes

Tags: python, selenium, flask, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

So I am calling a function run_script after clicking on value,

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result_page():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    auto_ui.open_headless(url) # passing url to open_headless function, of auto_ui.py module
    result = auto.run_script() # this will run all steps and return "pass" or "fail" string
    return render_template('result.html', header = result)
```

After the whole script finishes running, my logs are getting generated and screenshots are also being captured. So I am sure, the script has run. I am trying to display these results through results.html.

However the issue is,
after my flask app runs, and selenium devtools also start running:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://localhost:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2021 12:34:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -                       " 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2021 12:34:45] "GET /static/css/materialize.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
                                                                                                
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50124/devtools/browser/509c447d-58e5-42fc-a10d-6cb447e734f9
PS D:\
```

The issue is: post the whole script is run, my flask app quits automatically.
Is it because the selenium script is shutting it?
Is there a way to hold the flask session

Comment: Are you using `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()` to close the browser session ? I think this should close the browser instance.

Comment: Nope, but turns out it was due to some exception which is occurring while creating screenshots pdf and passing back filename.

Comment: Will figure out what's wrong and post it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough re-population to comment.

You can try making the session permanent:

```
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
```